# Create multiple Lists from one (Group List's Objects by a specific field)

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, java-stream

Given that I have the array of :

```
List<CustEnt> bulkList= CustRepo.fetchData();
//System.out.println(bulkList) -->
```

gives me :

```
    CustEct(name:"kasis",age:24,surname:"kumar"),CustEct(name:"samika",age:50,surname:"sharma"),CustEct(name:"manoj",age:84surname:"kumar")
OR
bulkList.get(1) --> CustEct(name:"kasis",age:24,surname:"kumar")
```

---

---

I **want to** create a new array which is grouped by the 3rd parameter of surname object.
So that my array becomes

```
ArrayFinal = [CustEct(name:"kasis",age:24,surname:"kumar"),CustEct(name:"samika",age:50,surname:"sharma")],CustEct(name:"manoj",age:84surname:"kumar")
```

So that when we do .get(1) we would get object of kasis and samika.

Need the help in respective to java 8.
I  heard that we can use the Map ,but can anyone give the small code sample or any other implementation guide.

Comment: I need to know what is the exact output of CustRepo.fetchData(). It's better if you show the implementation of CustRepo Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map` tracks key-value pairs.

- Your key is the surname string.
- Your value is a list of the `CustEnt` objects carrying that surname.

```java
Map<String, List<CustEnt>>
```

Modern syntax with streams and lambdas makes for brief code to place your objects in a map.

Something like:

```
Map<String, List<CustEnt>> map = originalList.stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustEnt::getSurename));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<CustEntity>> NamesList
        = bulkList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CustEntity::getSurames));

for (Map.Entry<String, List<CustEntity>> entry: NamesList.entrySet()) {
    ExcelGenerationService exp = new ExcelGenerationService( entry.getValue());
//service call
    exp.export(entry.getKey());
}
```